# How can I create account come with mnemonic use web3.py?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

account = web3.eth.account.create()
this account only have private_key and address,I want the mnemonic also,How can I do it?

For create a acount I want the result with private_key,address,mnemonic ...
How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
    >>> from eth_account import Account
    >>> Account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()
    >>> acct, mnemonic = Account.create_with_mnemonic()
    >>> acct.address # doctest: +SKIP
    '0x5ce9454909639D2D17A3F753ce7d93fa0b9aB12E'
    >>> acct == Account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic)
    True
```